# How to insert int into Println method in C++ (arduino) SMS module

Tags: c++, arduino, sms-gateway

how to insert integer into the println method for sms module.
this code doesnt work for me

```
SIM900.println("Your Score : %d ", cel " point");
```

or i've tried this one, but the it wont sent the integer. they just sent the string.

```
string point;
int cel;
String score;

SIM900.println(score);

point = String(cel);
score = "Your Score : ", point;
```

Comment: Cannot understand what do you do in both cases. Do you want to "send integer" as text or as binary data?

Comment: yes indeed, i want to send the integer data as text so my gsm module can send the integer into text.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
SIM900.println("Your Score : %d point", cel);
```

With the int value after all of the quoted text?

Comment: i guess so but the gsm module wont sent the int data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String` class. It has overload of `operator+` to concatenate strings and can convert integers to strings by constructor.

```
String message = "Your Score: " + String(cel) + " point";
SIM900.println(message);
```